# ruby base64 decode function limited 4KB in Windows

Tags: ruby, base64, decode, encode

I want to write png file from A xml including encoded png image by base64. First I tried like this

```
if (captureImageB64.length > 1)
    pngFile = File.new("xxx.png", "wb")
    captureImageB64.unpack('m').first
    pngFile.close
end
```

but this code makes 4KB png image. captureImageB64.unpack('m').first.length is 4096. so.. next version is

```
if (captureImageB64.length > 1)
    pngFile = File.new("xxx.png", "wb")
    i = 0
    while i < captureImageB64.length
        pngFile.write(captureImageB64.slice(i, 12).unpack('m').first)
        i += 12
    end
    pngFile.close
end
```

it makes broken png file. until 4096 is fine. How can I write the right file ?

I'm working on Windows7, ruby 2.0(x86).

---

Update:

I found padding string(==) in image file encoded base64. So it was encoded each 4096 byte! No one told me about that... I'll make a new encoder component.

Comment: so, your problem is, you try to decode base64 sliced at what seems like random positions, which don't align bytewise. maybe take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64 to learn more about finding the correct offsets.

Comment: thanks, your comment. when base64 decode 3 char to 4 byte. so it (12)is not random position. if it generate broken data, it could be last part becuase padding. actually i tried 3. I don't know why it makes 3byte output file.

Comment: could you try decoding the whole file to memory and then just write it in steps of 4k? maybe it's just your write buffer overflowing.

Comment: i want to decode whole file once. "captureImageB64.unpack('m').first" is 4096. how can i set buffer size?

Comment: no, you don't. because you do it in chunks in your second example. there's no reason why you should read everything into memory.